# Why rails respond with public/assets/application.js but not app/assets/javascripts/application.js in development mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, assets, sprockets

I was testing `turbo-sprockets` gem and precompiled assets locally. Since then `localhost:3000/assets/application.js` always respond with `public/assets/application.js` file (not `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`).

Solution is to remove `public/assets` folder. Is it normal behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you compile your assets with the production env, the generated assets are placed into `public/assets`. This is the first place Rails will search for assets : if you restart your app with development env, assets are already there and Rails won't search them in your `app/assets` directory anymore.

As stated in the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization) : "Any assets under `public` will be served as static files by the application or web server."

You're not supposed to precompile your assets on your development machine.

Comment: It is not clear how to avoid my situation. Remove `public/assets` every time after deployment? `config.assets.prefix` helps?

Comment: Don't you have a production environment ? On your development machine, you want your assets to be compiled on-the-fly every time you change something. On the production machine on the opposite you want to compile your assets only once.

Comment: I have one, but I usually precompile assets on the server, during deployment with capistrano.

Comment: That is the good approach. You should not precompile on your development environment and let the server precompile your assets for production. If for some reason you occasionally need to precompile assets in development, you'll have to remove the `public/assets` directory.

Comment: Heroku [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3x-asset-pipeline-cedar#the-asset-pipeline) says I can precompile assets locally and add them to git repo. Dont you think it's very bad solution?

Comment: It's not a **very bad** solution as you can always remove assets from your public `directory` and clear the cache, but it's not, in my humble opinion, the original design of the assets pipeline.